# Passing custom data to Stripe email receipt

Tags: laravel, email, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

I'm using Stripe's Payment Intents API (via a Payment Element) to accept payments on a site and automatically send email receipts on successful payment. I now need to send the product (a digital code) to the user inside of the receipt email, but the closest solution I've found to do this is using the `description` parameter of the Payment Intent object.

Unfortunately, Stripe displays the description as part of the order summary with a redundant item price right next to it:

[image]

This doesn't does look the best and I'd prefer to be able to pass in a separate section of the email, such as above the order summary.

Is there a more natural way this can be done with Stripe's email receipts?

Answer (score 1):

When passing custom data to Stripe email receipt, the solution you found (e.g. to pass that data via the [`description` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-description)) is the only option on the [automatic email receipts](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#customizing-receipts). Alternatively, you can listen to [`payment_intent.succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded) webhook [event](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) and handle emails from your end.